# Bluetooth Headset to Bluetooth Transceiver

Tags: arduino, wireless, bluetooth, transceiver, wearable

I have a little bit of experience with Bluetooth and Arduinos but I was wondering if anyone might be able to tell me if it is possible for a Bluetooth headset to be linked to a Bluetooth transceiver connected to an Arduino microcontroller? I know that when you link a Bluetooth headset to your smartphone, there are usually some steps you have to take on your phone to confirm the headset. And if its not possible to link it like you would normally link to a smart phone, could I manually assign it to connect to only one headset in the code on the Arduino?... Sort of like a static address assignment for the Bluetooth Personal Area Network. Any thoughts or comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the bluetooth device you plan on using with the arduino, both on the arudino end and the headset itself.  You would have to make sure both sides support the same protocol (Example: SSP).  However, even so the Arduino software implementation of BT only supports SPP (serial) rather than HFP (hands free) which is used on bluetooth headsets.

You would need one of the new A2DP sterio headsets which ARE supported by the arduino software and many modems.   In short, you would need both a headset and arduino BT module that support A2DP to get this to work.  However, I have no idea how you hope to process sterio audio on an arduino.  Good luck.